# ORACLE SQL Developer (Query)

Tags: sql, oracle

The question that I would like to answer is: Present the average number of students who travel in a particular route per week.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT SUM(NO_OF_SEATS) "WEEKLY AVG"
FROM RESER;
```

This code shows me the average number of students only, but I want the average per week and I don't know how to get that.

I tried this but it's wrong:

```
SELECT SUM(NO_OF_SEATS) "WEEKLY AVG"
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MIN(TRAVEL_DATE), 'WW') + 1, 'FORMAT')
FROM RESER;
```

Comment: What error or issue are you getting with your query you tried?

Comment: Some Very odd data if `SUM()` = `AVG()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(NO_OF_SEATS) "WEEKLY AVERAGE", TRUNC(TRAVEL_DATE,'IW')
FROM RESER
GROUP BY TRUNC(TRAVEL_DATE,'IW');
```

**'WW'** = Assumes the first day starts on January 1st and will go in 7 day increments.  Weeks will potentially start on a day that is not Monday.
**'IW'** = Will always start the week on a Monday.

Comment: @user5520587 - if MikeS's answer worked for you, you may want to mark it as "Correct Answer" - otherwise the question will continue to show among the unanswered questions. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't mind having another correct answer under my belt as well.  Thanks!